# Understanding derivation of expectation value of power of momentum operator

Tags: fourier-transform, quantum-mechanics

I have been reading through the book Fourier Series and Integrals by Dym and McKean. In one of their derivations, they have the following line
$$
\int \psi^* B^n \psi = \int \psi^* [(2\pi i)^{-1} D]^n \psi = \int \hat\psi^* \gamma^n \hat\psi = \int \gamma^n |\hat\psi|^2
$$
Where they define the momentum operator $B$ as $B = (2\pi i)^{-1} D$, with $D$ representing the differentiation operator. However, I'm not sure how the second equality follows. We have the identity $(2\pi i \gamma)^p D^q \hat f = \left[D^p (-2\pi i x)^qf\right]\hat{}$, but I don't see how this gets us what we want and in particular how $\psi^*$ turns into $\hat\psi^*$. Could I get some guidance?

Comment: Have you tried using Parseval's theorem?

Comment: @F_M_ I'm not quite sure how that could help here. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I am not familiar with the book, but if you want to introduce the fourier transform in the integral, I would use Parseval, which says that (under some conditions) $\int f g = \int \hat{f} \hat{g}.$

Comment: Consider the case $n=1.$ Then (let me neglect the multiples of $2\pi i$ by using $\sim$) we have $\int \psi^*(x)  \psi'(x)\mathrm{d}x \sim \int \widehat{\psi^*} (\gamma)\widehat{\psi'}(\gamma)\mathrm{d}\gamma \sim \int \widehat{\psi^*}(\gamma) \gamma \widehat{\psi}(\gamma)\mathrm{d}\gamma.$ A similar argument should work for general $n.$

Comment: I posted an answer, I hope it is clear now @Subhasish Mukherjee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second equality is explained as follows. Using the Parseval Theorem we have
\begin{align*}
\int \psi^*(x) \left[ (2\pi i)^{-1} D\right]^n \psi(x) \mathrm{d}x &= \int \frac{1}{(2\pi i)^n}\widehat{\psi^*}(\gamma) \widehat{D^n \psi}(\gamma) \mathrm{d}\gamma \\
&= \frac{1}{(2\pi i)^n} \int \widehat{\psi^*}(\gamma)(2\pi i)^n\gamma^n \widehat{\psi}(\gamma)\mathrm{d}\gamma,
\end{align*}
where we used the differentiation rule $\widehat{f^{(n)}}(\gamma) = (2\pi i \gamma)^n \widehat{f}(\gamma).$